# Need a regex expression to validate a java string

Tags: java, regex

I need a java regex expression which can allow a string containing Alpha Numeric, space, hyphen, aphostophy, `&`, `()`, `"`, min 1 characters and max 100 Characters.

I tried with `` ^[a-zA-Z -`&(),\"]{1,100}$ ``. But it is returning true in conditions where string contains `*` or `|` etc.

Comment: Escape the `-` in the character class or place it at the start or end. This way it will create a range.

Comment: `^[-a-zA-Z \`&(),"]{1,100}$` as an unescaped `-` must be at first or last position in a character class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this: `^[a-zA-Z0-9 \-`&(),"]{1,100}$`

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/9nQ2JD/1/